# Is it possible to disable restarts in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown, reboot

My laptop has a weird issue where the touch pad doesn't work after the device is restarted. It works fine after a normal shut down, though.

Is it possible to disable restarts so that the computer will always shut down fully?

Comment: What kind of restarts? Started how?

Comment: If you disable restarts, you will not be able to update other apps or complete the install of new apps. Update the Mouse Driver and perhaps BIOS.

Comment: To piggyback on @John's comments, troubleshoot the touchpad instead of looking for a workaround, as Windows itself isn't the issue and it's likely the driver. Run the UEFI/BIOS hardware diagnostics [long test] on the touchpad after a reboot _(it's accessible either from the UEFI/BIOS boot page or from within the UEFI/BIOS settings)_ - if the touchpad passes, it's driver related.

Comment: There are two additional duplicate candidates which I will add after I get to work

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. I'm not asking about automatic updates specifically, but about disabling any type of restart.

Comment: @JW0914 - I've already tried that. The hardware test passes fine but the manufacturer's driver is defective.

Comment: @Pikamander2 Uninstall the PC's OEM driver and either grab it directly from the touchpad's OEM [e.g. Synaptics, etc.] or use the generic Windows touchpad driver, as touchpads always work without the PC's OEM/touchpad's OEM driver, you simply lose the extra customizable features of the touchpad _(scroll zones, double/triple tap, etc.)_